# How to load data from pgAdminIII with PHP and ajax into a leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, leaflet

I have three dropdowns where my user can select the table, field and attribute. I used the selected results from the dropdowns to make a query. But now i want to get that on my leaflet map but i don't know how.

This is my getData.php code:

```
<?php

include "connect.php";

$table          = $_GET['tableSelected'];
$field         = $_GET['fieldSelected'];
$attribute      = $_GET['attributeSelected'];

$sql = "SELECT $fieldstr
        FROM $table l" ; 
        WHERE $field = $attribute";

if (!$response = pg_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "A query error occured.\n";
    exit;
}

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($response)) {
    foreach ($row as $i => $attr){
        echo $attr.", ";
    }
    echo ";";
}

?>
```

And this is my main.js code:

```
$('#slctTable, #slctField, #slctAttribute').change(function ()
{
    var tableSelected = document.getElementById("slctTable").value;
    var fieldSelected = document.getElementById("slctField").value;
    var attributeSelected = document.getElementById("slctAttribute").value;
    $.ajax({
        "url": "php/getData.php",
        "type": "GET",
        "data": {
            tableSelected: tableSelected,
            fieldSelected: fieldSelected,
            attributeSelected: attributeSelected
        }
    })
});

//Initalise map
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize(){
    $("#map").height($(window).height());

    map = L.map("map", {
        center: L.latLng(53.21587, 6.556676 ),
        zoom: 12
    });

    var tileLayer = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(map);
};
```

**UPDATE**

This is what i get back at the moment:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move your `change` listener into your `initialize`(so it can work with `map`..... add a `success` function to your [ajax options](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) like the below.

```
    $.ajax({
    "url": "php/getData.php",
    "type": "GET",
    "data": {
        tableSelected: tableSelected,
        fieldSelected: fieldSelected,
        attributeSelected: attributeSelected
    },
    'success': function(data) {
      //perform data transformation to a leaflet compatible format
      ///then map.addLayer(transformedStuff)
    }

})
```

Comment: I made the changes you said. But i don't know how to write the code for the transformation to a Geojson file. And how should my php file look like? Because i think i'm missing some stuff there too.

Comment: what does the response from your database look like? WKT?Geojson?

Comment: I edited my question. This is how I'm getting it back at the moment. See update. It is a JSON file with latitude and longitude.

Comment: Can you post the full screenshot? I don't see the coordinates in the one you posted.

Comment: I think i got it back as a geojson now. The thing is i now need to write a code that prints it in on the leaflet map. I updated the response i got.

Comment: Why are there semicolons before each object?Can you just dump it cleanly as an JSON array?